# How to remove html characters while updating web.config?

Tags: c#

I have a simple winforms application that allows admins to update the connection String . Admin would type in the updated connection String and it would be saved in the modified web.config file. But I am unable to remove html characters like > < that get saved while updating the connection String.

I tried HttpUlitity.HtmlDecode but that did not work out . The update code snippet looks like :

```
   private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var configFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Test\Websites\AccountDeduplicationWeb\web.config");
            var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
            var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
            wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
            var configSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            String connString = String.Empty;
            if (configSection != null)
            {
                var xElement = XElement.Parse(configTextBox.Text);
                connString = xElement.Attribute["connectionString"].Value;
                configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(connString);
                config.Save();

                //var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
                //connString = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;
                //configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
                //config.Save();
            }
            updateMessageLabel.Text = "Config Updated Successfully !! ";
            showDecryptedConfig();
        }
```

If the eneterd connection String is something like

then this code updates it to

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ARCHQConnection" connectionString="&lt;connectionStrings&gt;&#xA;    &lt;add name=&quot;ARCHQConnection&quot; connectionString=&quot;LDAP://exeterblr.com/DC=exeterblr.SA,DC=in&quot; /&gt;&#xA;  &lt;/connectionStrings&gt;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

even though I tried it to be updated with

```
<add name="ARCHQConnection" connectionString="LDAP://exeterblr.com/DC=exeterblr.SA,DC=in" />
```

Comment: HTML characters are *not* your problem. You are storing what looks like an attribute-value pair in the connectionstring attribute, not just the value. What is the value of `connstring`?

Comment: How can I achieve so ? And display the updated connection String value ?

Comment: What *are* you storing in there? What is the value of `connString`? What is the content of `configTextBox.Text`? If it was a proper connection string you *wouldn't* have issues. At the very least it contains the word `connectionString` in it, but I suspect it's actually an entire ConnectionStrings element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can try this:

I have changed var to string 
and

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` function has been applied to next line. see if that helps you.

```
string connString = configTextBox.Text;
configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(connString);
config.Save();
```

Just realized that you are sending the complete XML to the Textbox and thus you need to get the value of the connectionstring attribute like this

```
var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
connString  = xElement.Attribute["connectionString"].Value;
configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
config.Save();
```

### **Updated Code**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(configTextBox.Text); 
XmlNode ConnStr = doc.getElementByTagName("add");
connString = ConnStr.Attributes["connectionString"].Value
configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
config.Save();
```

Comment: connString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(configTextBox.Text);
                var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
                connString = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;
                configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
                config.Save();

throws a null reference exception

Comment: No. It should be `var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
connString  = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;` **than** `configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
config.Save();`

Comment: It sill throws NullReference exception at connString  = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group' .. error :(

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

The Logic of your code is wrong. Your code only updates the connection string attribute, but you insert the whole XML Element.

**A solution** would be to only insert `LDAP://exeterblr.com/DC=exeterblr.SA,DC=in` into your textbox.

**Another solution** would be to receive the connectionString attribute with this code:

```
var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
connString  = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @David
 connString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(configTextBox.Text);
                var xElement = XElement.Parse(connString);
                connString = xElement.Attribute("connectionString").Value;
                configSection.ConnectionStrings["ARCHQConnection"].ConnectionString = connString;
                config.Save();
throws a null reference eception at xElement.Attribute("connectionString").value